# How to configure a digicert CNG certificate in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate, digicert

we're trying to configure a client-provided certificate which was issued by the DigiCert CA for authentication in a WCF service.

Unfortunately, the utility we need to run isn't able to parse the certificate and gives a `Unexpected error: Invalid provider type specified.` error.

It seems the error means that the format of the certificate is CNG instead of CAPI, and apparently .NET 4 and higher should be able to accept those.  But we're still not sure how to enter that into app.config to make .NET recognize the certificate.  Below is the app.config file contents with the endpoint certificate authentication.

Could someone please offer some advice?  Thank you in advance.

```
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="2449997a30a8c9df29bd43c1eaa91cb47d89b0cb" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>            
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <client>
      <endpoint name="Download" address="http://mywebserviceurl.com/MobileService/WebService2.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TheWsHttpBinding" contract="MyApp.FileClient.IDownloadService">
        <identity>
          <certificate encodedValue="*****"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TheWsHttpBinding">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are using .NET Framework 4.6.1 or below:

> .NET Framework 4.6.1 and earlier versions do not support these certificates because they use the legacy CryptoAPI to handle CNG/KSP certificates. The use of these certificates with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and earlier versions will cause an exception.
> [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/unsupported-scenarios)